# Using SED to insert date and time before HTML tag

Tags: sed

Sorry if variances of this have been asked before, but I still can't figure it out!

I want to use a Windows port of SED to insert the date and time before instances of the  tag.

I  figured I would try to replace all instances of `</span>` with `%date% at %time%</span>`

I tried to do it with this construction:

```
sed s/</span>/"%date% at %time%"</span>/ <file >file2
```

But I get also sorts of errors when I try. And yes, I know I have to escape `<` and `/` and `>` with an escape character (e.g. I read I should  use `/` to do it) but it still does not work. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Which language? Sed can't magically determine the current date and time so for example you have to store it in a variable for sed to use it.

Comment: I am using SED in a windows 7 bat file to act on an HTML file. The %date% and %time% stuff are Windows environmental variables, so that part is not the problem. All I want to do now is replace all instances of </span> with  %date% at %time%</span> 

I tried
sed s/</span>/%date% at %time%"</span>/ <banner.ref >banner.html
but no cigar. So I am hoping somebody can tell me how to write this command correctly.

Thanks for your time in any event!

Answer (score 0):

Protection of special char should use backslash instead of `/`. You can also choose a
different sed substitute separator char (example `!`) to avoid the necessity of protecting
`/` char.

I was expecting something like:

```
sed -e 's!</span>!%date% at %time%!g' file > file2
```

- g stands for global (substitute all occurrences)

(I can't speak windows so probably some quotes need to be fixed)

Be carefull because `</span>` is widely used in html pages... Probably a  specific 
mark `<date>` would be a best strategy.

This time using perl:

```
perl -pe 's!<date>!localtime!eg' file > file2
```

- eg = eval substitute `<date>` by the evaluation of the string `localtime`

Comment: Thank you! I will try all your advice! Happy Thanksgiving (assuming that is one you celebrate)!

Comment: Very happy Thanksgiving to you too!